# How to align molecules structure at the base line?

Tags: chemfig

I am using ChemFig package to compile some molecule structures, however, I cannot align them at the base line. See picture 1. How could I align all the molecules, the arrow and "+" sign in the reaction exactly at the same level? Moreover, how to maintain the same alignment while adding chemical names under the molecules using \chemname{} command? Say the chemical names are A, B, C and D, respectively, as shown in picture 1? Thanks.
[image: picture 1]

Tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=-=(-CH_3)-=)} \arrow{->[\chemfig{F_2}][\chemfig{MeOH}][]}[,1.5]
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=-(-F)=(-CH_3)-=)}
\+
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=(-F)-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\+{,,5pt}
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-(-F)=-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the anchors of the compounds for alignment using the `\arrow(.<anchor>--<anchor>)` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vphantom` aligns molecules, additional argument of `\+` aligns plus signs and arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\vphantom{\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-(-F)=-=(-CH_3)-=)}} % here - PS
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=-=(-CH_3)-=)} 
\arrow{->[\chemfig{F_2}][\chemfig{MeOH}][]}[,1.5]
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=-(-F)=(-CH_3)-=)}
\+{,,5pt} % here - PS
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-=(-F)-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\+{,,5pt}
\chemfig{[,0.5]*6(-(-F)=-=(-CH_3)-=)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Scherwentk: How could I add the molecule name under the  the molecule structure using \chemname{} command while maintaining the alignment? Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Can you give proper names, please? Or should I simply give dummy names?

Comment: @scherwentk: I revised the problem. Yes, any names are OK. thanks.