# How to align all the molecules, the + sign and arrow at the same level?

Tags: chemfig

I use the `chemfig` package to draw molecules in a chemical reaction. However, I cannot align the molecules, the `+` sign and arrow at the base line. I have tried the `\vphantom` command, **[like in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276484/how-to-align-molecules-structure-at-the-base-line)**. But it does not work. I cannot use the  `\chemfig{}` command to shift the molecules up or down. How could I handle this type of problem when using `chemfig`? Any tricks for new `chemfig` learners?
Here's my output so far:
 [image]

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setatomsep{3em}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{O=[:-90](-[:-150]H)-[:-30]OH}}{Formic acid} 
\+{2em, 2em, -3em} 
\vphantom{\+{,, -3em}}%
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3OH}}{Methanol}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemname{\chemfig{O=[:-90](-[:-150]H)-[:-30]O-[:30]}}{Methyl formiate} 
\+{2em, 2em, -3em} 
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`chemfig` always places the first atom of the molecule on the baseline, so if you write

```
\chemfig{O=[:-90](-[:-150]H)-[:-30]OH}
```

the oxygen will be on the baseline. To put the carbon on the baseline it has to be the first atom:

```
\chemfig{(-[:-150]H)(=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}
```

In other words, you must start from the atom you want to be on the baseline and treat the others like branchings. The code is therefore

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setatomsep{3em}
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{(-[:-150]H)(=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}}{Formic acid}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{CH_3OH}}{Methanol}
\arrow{<=>}
\chemname{\chemfig{(-[:-150]H)(=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30]}}{Methyl formiate}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{H_2O}}{Water}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `\chemfig{H-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}`?

Comment: And maybe align the arrow, too: `\arrow(.base east--.base west){<=>[][][4pt]}`

Comment: @arch Stanton: Thanks for your reply. It works, but the name the names below the molecules are a little far away. any idea to tackle this?

Comment: @clemens `\chemfig{H-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]OH}` places the hydrogen on the baseline so the molecule sits too high imo, I prefer to put the carbon chain on the baseline, even if it's a single carbon. I ignored the arrow alignment because it is beyond the scope of the question but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: @Nick You can specify the distance between the molecule and the name with the optional argument of `\chemname`: `\chemname[<dim>]{...}`. I suggest you to read the documentation of the package (always, for any package), see `\chemnameinit` in particular. That may be useful (not in this case, but it would if you wrote the alcohol before the acid).

Comment: @ArchStanton: Thank you for you help, Stanton.

Comment: @ArchStanton I find it much nicer if the letters are aligned :)

Comment: @clemens: Could you post your solution? BTW, how could I increase the distance between the edges of the compounds and the beginning and end of the arrows? I tried \setarrowoffset, but the arrow shrinks and get shorter. I want to keep the length of the arrow.

Comment: @Nick my answer would basically be the same as Arch's: change the definition of the molecules appropriately so their baseline is changed which then will make alignment easier. I'm not sure this justifies a new answer…

Answer (score -2):

Chemical formula are very difficult to do properly even with a good package like Chemfig.  I would switch to a dedicated application like ChemDraw which has all of the functionality that you need for this problem as well all the extras for other more complex examples.

Sometimes one has to recognise that TeX/LaTeX cannot do it all ... more's the pity

Comment: That's a valid opinion and I even agree but it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: Chemfig can do what the OP has asked (and much more).

Comment: "Horses for courses"